# Where Do I move files if I want to delete OneDrive

Tags: windows-10

Recently I moved my files to OneDrive..Now, I would like to stop using OneDrive, I am just wondering which "folder" to I copy the OneDrive files to?? Do I use "C drive"? My documents? I would appreciate your help! Thx!

Comment: You should move the files, do not delete them, from the OneDrive to whatever location you wish.  If you delete them from OneDrive you will synchronize that change and the cloud file will also be deleted.

Answer (score 1):

Copy the files /  folders from your One Drive folder to a different folder of your choice - NOT in the One Drive folder but elsewhere in Documents.

Once the files are securely elsewhere (indeed, put them on a USB key temporarily as well), delete the One Drive folder.

Just be sure you have a secure back up before deleting the One Drive folders.